# Cakephp Validation

Tags: cakephp, validation, cakephp-1.3

I am using an Account Controller which doesnt have its own table but uses User Model.

All works fine except - when I validate any form. It says validation fails (when I try to fail the validation to check) but doesnt throw the error below the field

View

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id'); ?>
              <label for="UserPassword">New Password:</label>
              <?php echo $this->Form->text('password', array('type' => 'password', 'value' => 'harsha')); ?><em>Password must be min 6 characters.</em> <?php echo $form->error('password'); ?>
```

Controller Action

```
            if($this->User->saveField('password', $this->data['User']['password'], array('validate' => 'first'))) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Password has been changed.', 'flash-success');
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('There was some problem with our system. Please try after some time.', 'flash-warning');
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `debug()`ing the contents of `$this->validationErrors` in your view, as well as `$this->data` in your controller just after a form submission. This should give you a lot more information to work from.

I suspect that your problem is Cake is building form inputs based on the wrong model -- building form fields for `Account.id` and `Account.password` instead of `User.id` and `User.password`. This is because `FormHelper` takes its default model from the controller/view it's invoked from, which in your case appears `AccountsController`.

In order to generate the `User.id` and `User.password` fields your controller's submission handling expects, you'll need to prepend `User.` in your `FormHelper` calls. Thus:

```
$this->Form->input('User.id');
$this->Form->text('User.password');
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

`echo $session->flash()`;

Note that whatever the manual says, it returns, not echoes. I logged this a while back and it has been changed in the 1.3 manual, but not the 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you who's asking 
If you want to show error-message that return from UserModel's validate 
 So you can add line code bellow after input form password

```
  <?php 
      if ($this->Form->isFieldError('password')) { 
       echo $this->Form->error('password', array('class' => 'error')); 
    ?>
```

and if you want to show error-message that set by method setFlash
you must redirect page and then use $this->Session->flash('flash-name') in page you want to show it

```
   <?php
    //in UsersController
    $this->Session->setFlash('message here', 'flash-name');
    //in view
    echo $this->Session->flash('flash-name');
   ?>
```

Good luck!